# How to group by for one column within a list of dataframes

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes.

Each dataframe is named by person and each dataframe contains events (the row). The columns for each event are called 'Indication for event' and 'Number of biopsies' . I would like to create a summary dataframe (or matrix?) that tells me how many biopsies are taken for each Indication by each person.

```
List of 3
 $ :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Indication: Factor w/ 2 levels "AbdoPain","Vomiting": 1 2 1
  ..$ NumOfBx   : num [1:3] 2 3 1
 $ :'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Indication: Factor w/ 3 levels "AbdoPain","Anaemia",..: 2 2 1 3
  ..$ NumOfBx   : num [1:4] 12 23 1 5
 $ :'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Indication: Factor w/ 3 levels "AbdoPain","Anaemia",..: 2 1 3 3
  ..$ NumOfBx   : num [1:4] 1 2 3 7
```

The results:

```
           dfMrBen      dfJohn        dfStuart
Abdo pain
Vomiting
Anaemia
```

I thought this was likely to be a split-apply-combine problem but I don't know how to combine to get the summary as above. At the moment I have:

```
ReportOp<-function(x){
#To extract the dataframe name
theName<-x
#To extract the dataframe data
x<-data.frame(Dxlst[[x]])
grp<-x%>% group_by(Indication %>% summarise(mean=mean(NumberOfBx)
}
lapply(names(Dxlst,ReportOp)
```

but this just gives me the summary for each dataframe. How do I combine basically add the dataframes together to get the intended result?

Comment: Please give `dput` of the data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first combine the data in one big dataframe or do this after summary with

```
do.call(rbind, Dxlst)
```

or first add id's to each list and then `rbind` them together like so:

```
Dxlst <- lapply(1:length(Dxlst), 
  function(x) cbind(Dxlst[[x]],
    id = rep(x,nrow(Dxlst[[x]]))))

do.call(rbind, Dxlst)
```

Comment: Or in fact maybe I shouldn't have split this in the first place and I am over complicating things :) your answer works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for. But it is close. Also you should combine the data frame then so a summary which would be simpler.

Create the data:-

```
df1=data.frame(Indication=as.factor(sample(c(0,1), 10, replace = T)), Bx=sample(1:10, 10, replace = T))
df2=data.frame(Indication=as.factor(sample(c(0,1,2), 10, replace = T)), Bx=sample(1:10, 10, replace = T))
l=list(df1,df2)
```

then

```
l=lapply(l, function(x) aggregate( Bx ~ Indication, x, sum))
m=max(sapply(l, nrow))
n=lapply(l, function(x){ x <- x[seq_len(m),]; row.names(x) <- NULL; x})
do.call('cbind',n)
```

I get output like:

```
Indication Bx Indication Bx
1          0 18          0  9
2          1 28          1 35
3       <NA> NA          2 18
```